# Gulp rollup in parrallel task and series

Tags: gulp, rollup

I have a gulpfile as below with a rollupTask. But at the last task which zipTask, it output without bundled js from rollup. The only way i found that fix this is to add wait time before the ziptask. There seems to be a fraction of delay with rollup output and the next gulp series.  Is this the expected behavior or there is something that fix this without add waiting time ? Is my rollupTask is correct ? the zip tasks simply zip the output folder into a different folder. The output folder itself contain the expected bundle.

```js
const gulp = require('gulp');
const rollup = require('rollup');

async function rollupTask() {
  const rollupBuild = await rollup({
    input: 'index.js',
    plugins: rollupPlugins,
  });
  await rollupBuild.write({
    file: 'bundle.js',
    format: 'es',
    sourcemap: true,
  });
  await rollupBuild.close();
}

exports.default = series(taskOne, parallel(taskTwo, taskThree, rollupTask), zipTask);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a plugin written for gulp. [gulp-rollup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rollup)

```js
const { src, dest } = require('gulp');
const rollup = require('gulp-rollup');
 
function rollupTask() {
    const options = { input: './src/main.js' } // any option supported by Rollup can be set here.
    return src('./src/**/*.js')
        .pipe(rollup(options)) // transform the files here.
        .pipe(dest('./dist'));
}

exports.build = series(rollupTask);
```

On start: `gulp build`